# How to safely expand root partition for Xubuntu running in VirtualBox with GParted?

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, gparted

I tried it once and it worked fine for a day or two. However, upon rebooting it failed. I can't even get to recovery menu. All I see is a hyphen. Fortunately, I had made a back up of the VDI file.

The root partition is running out of space. My Home directory is in the larger partition. Previously, I had essentially moved everything to the right, except the unallocated space which was moved next to root. I then expanded the root. It worked the first time I booted into it, but it's failing now. Where did I go wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous modified volume just needed a boot-repair. I booted into live cd and installed boot-repair. It automatically fixed my issue.